# Moving a tab and docking it in Avalondock 3.2 makes program unresponsive until loses/gains focus

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, avalondock

I'm working with a touch screen.  If I use a mouse and drag and drop the tabs to dock them, it works great.  If I drag and drop a tab with my finger however, the moment it docks, the window becomes unresponsive (GUI animations will still animate, like flashing colors, etc) but no input is received until the program loses focus and then gains it again.

I'm using a version of AvalonDock 3.2 that my work modified and I can't upgrade or modify it.  What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I pressume you are using the open source version of AvalonDock? This version is known to have many critical issues:

1) See [here](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/wiki/Patch-History) for known issues in AvalonDock 3.2 - 3.4
2) See [bottom of this page](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock) for known issues in AvalonDock 3.5

So, you have at least 2 options:

1. You can either try to migrate to a [stabilized version in this repository](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock)
   and see if this fixes your problem or
2. Pay money - although I am pretty sure Xceed's
   [fixing only their active version](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1440#issuecomment-490520006) (right now 3.8)
   so you'd have to migrate anyways

An upgrade from 3.2 to 3.5 should be easy - just replace the reference with another binary and recompile to see if your problem was fixed in 3.5. If not, try to re-produce your problem with a smaller program and report the issue.

I don't think you will get a suitable resolution here (based on the non-existing evidence (reproducable sample code) given in this Stackoverflow item).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem like yours, when I am using my mouse to dock the tab everything works fine but when I move to my touch screen monitor the issue start to happen. After making my self suffer for a week, I finally found a cheat way to solve this issue. (I will try my best to make the explanation short)

I found that when the tab is drag and drop the mouse will be captured by one of the control, I can't find out the exact control which capturing the mouse. But I just **release the mouse captured** in one of the events and everything solve.

Before adding a long code like me, just try and see whether your issue is same like mine.
For testing, u can add a **MouseDown** or **MouseUp** event over the **DockingManager**, in that event add two lines of code:

```
CaptureMouse();
ReleaseMouseCapture();
```

(this code is to capture the mouse and release it, so after this two line of code, your UI might not have any control capturing the mouse already)

Testing over the UI: when you dock your tab by right your view should be "not responding", try click on the **tab content**, and it might trigger the event that you just added, the captured mouse will release, and now everything should back to normal.

OK, after testing the code above and the issue seems like solved then you may proceed to a longer code or you think it is ok to stop here is all up to you,
just for reference my actual way to solve this "unresponsive" issue is:

Adding a **MouseMove** event, in this event I will check whether the mouse is dragging anything, if yes I will continue to run a **Task** to monitor the mouse event until the left button released, when the left button released I will add those two line to capture and release the mouse.

Here is my code:

```
private void UserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            UserDragDrop(e);
        }
    }

    private async void UserDragDrop(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                MouseEventArgs _e = (MouseEventArgs)e;
                while (_e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waitiing");
                    if (_e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Release");
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            CaptureMouse();
                            ReleaseMouseCapture();
                        }));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exp called");
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    var vosk_border = VOSK.BorderBrush;
                    VOSK.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
                    CaptureMouse();
                    ReleaseMouseCapture();
                    VOSK.BorderBrush = vosk_border;
                }));
            }

        });
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

(when you test, suggest you to test with your touch screen device and also your mouse to make sure it works on your mouse and also your finger)

This may not be the best way to solve this issue but so far this is the method that I can think of, if anyone else able to suggest me a better way to do this will be great!
FYI, this code will prompt a null reference exception and I can't figure out where is the null source. I am not a expert programmer. Just trying to help, because I understand dealing with Avalon Dock is very complicated and time consuming!
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: https://doc.xceed.com/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock~Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DockingManager_events.html#
here is the link for your reference if you need to get the respective event.